# How can I use my small flashlight as my bicycle's headlight?

Tags: headlights

How safely add my small flashlight to my foldable bicycle temporarily? I want use it as headlight. But I need take it off when I don't bike.  My folding bicycle doesn't have basket, and I don't want add basket.

Because COVID19, I don't want spend money buying light. My small flashlight has a handle.Let me know if you want me write out flashlight name and model.

[Michael](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/71563) wrote below

> In any case, please make sure to mount it in a way which doesn’t dazzle oncoming traffic.

[Criggie](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/71562/how-can-i-use-my-small-flashlight-as-my-bicycles-headlight#comment163364_71562)

> I'd suggest angling this down at the road more than forward.

OK! I know. You can adjust [lumens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D433S.jpg), and I use just 80 lms in day and 800 lms at night.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your folding bike have a stem or is it the sort with a T shaped handlebar?

Comment: What are you doing about a red rear light?

Comment: @Criggie Do you have pics of "stem"? Don't know this means. Red rear light is still working fine!

Comment: @Criggie Do you think I should add flashlight manufacturer and model?

Comment: That rather fat light looks awkward but there are certainly cheap rubber devices to mount thinner ones an handlebars. There may be something suitable for that too

Comment: @tak no the brand is not important.  We can see its a fairly thick body - most bike lights would be a lot thinner.  Proper bike lights are designed to throw the light better - your photo shows this is a flood and is likely to dazzle or distract other road users.  I'd suggest angling this down at the road more than forward.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to bolt something in place where the handle is in the top picture.

Comment: It is not small, it is pretty big (for a flashlight)

Comment: I think that a decent cycle light with a strong enough beam would certainly be better in this case than a probably not road-use legal flashlight in a wobbly DIY holder. Less prone to fall off and be a danger to following traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GoPro mounting parts and zip-ties to create a detachable bicycle lamp. It mounts to a base with a three-pronged plastic part and M5 bolt. Either can be used to temporarily detach the lamp.

I used it this way to attach my much smaller handheld torch to helmet:

[image: gopro and lamp]

[image: attached]

Using the same system, you can attach it to the handlebar using a "gopro handlebar mount". On the picture below, mentally replace the camera unit with your lamp in order to understand how it would look like.

[image: gopro]

You do not need to buy original parts by GoPro, there are many compatible cheaper alternatives to it.

Comment: Do be careful what you mount to a helmet - they're not designed to provide the same level of protection when things are strapped to the outside.   Avoid attaching to the front, sides or top of the helmet - the rear and upper/rear are better, because you're less likely to hit those areas of your head in an accident.

Comment: @cRiggie Yes, I am aware about the dangers of attaching stuff to the helmet. The light in question is my auxiliary/emergency light to be always kept on me but rarely mounted/used. Basically only in situations when the main bicycle light fails or I am unexpectedly late in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

Can you maybe use zip ties to mount the handle to the stem, then attach the flashlight to the handle when needed? Can be tricky to get the angle right.

There are also universal flash light mounts, though I’m not sure they’ll work for the rather large diameter of yours.

In any case, please make sure to mount it in a way which doesn’t dazzle oncoming traffic.

Comment: zip ties, cable ties, slip ties are all regional names for the same thing.  Other subtitutes include cord/twine/rope in a square lashing, several layers of duct tape, or even velcro/hook-loop fastener based cable ties.

Comment: I'd also suggest hanging the torch/flashlight below the bars, where its more stable under vibration.  A top-mounted one wants to do a sudden 180 flip and light up one's knees.

Comment: I hope you realize that it is impossible to mount a radially symmetric flashlight in a manner that doesn't dazzle oncoming traffic, while at the same time allowing enough forwards visibility. There is a reason why good StVZO (German law) compliant lights are used on bicycles instead of radially symmetric flashlights.

Comment: @juhist: Yes, it’s sad how common radially symmetric lights on bicycles are. I think if you angle them downwards far enough it can work somewhat (at the cost of visibility, as you said). But one should really test and adjust this carefully and make sure it doesn’t tilt.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks. You can't add pictures to comments, but if you got time, please post new answer and add pictures?

Comment: @Michael "Can you maybe use zip ties to mount the handle to the stem, then attach the flashlight to the handle when needed?" Can you picture this please? Not wholly sure what you mean.

Comment: @tak the stem is described in our terminology index at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/270/19705   If you strap your light to that part of your bike, it will probably aim upwards too much.   But you could make a new "handle"  with more angle, and strap the handle to your stem so the light goes on the road.   Or bend the existing handle.